# Restore MacOS system Python3 version

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I somehow managed to mess up my system-wide Python3 installation for my fresh MacOS Catalina installation. The problem is with pip – I upgraded the system pip version with `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip`. After doing so, I got error messages from pip saying:

`WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip. Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue. To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.`

Then, in a (failed) attempt to downgrade pip to the previous version to remove this error, I uninstalled this version of pip with `sudo pip3 uninstall pip` - not my smartest move, I know. Now, with `pip3 –version` I get the following output:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module> from pip._internal import main ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'`

I know I can install other versions of python and pip with brew (this is what I am currently doing), but I know that a fair number of system services and applications rely on the system-installed python, so I would like to fix this issue.

Comment: Python should still be installed, since you only uninstalled pip. Just reinstall pip.

Comment: @ShaneBishop how though? If I run `pip3 install pip` it just gives the same error?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo pip3 uninstall pip` will only uninstall pip, it won't uninstall python. You can just reinstall pip.

To reinstall pip:

```sh
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --user
rm get-pip.py
```

Then you should run pip as `python3 -m pip` instead of `pip3`, or else create an alias for `pip3` in your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bashrc`/`~/.bash_aliases` for Linux bash users):

```sh
alias pip3='python3 -m pip'
```

Comment: This is a user installation? If I run the second line as sudo and without --user will that restore the equivalent of system-wide pip that was installed by default?

Comment: It should, yes. Just no guarantee it will be the exact same version of pip as before. But if its a newer version, it shouldn't break anything.

Comment: Thanks Shane. running `sudo python3 get-pip.py pip==19.0.3` fixes everything. It turns out 19.0.3 is the version that ships with Catalina, the newer version has the warning mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: By the way, the warning was only because you were running pip with `pip3`. If you do upgrade pip again, you should run pip with `python3 -m pip` instead, and then you won't receive any warnings.